# How to start a family tree?

Tags: information

I have a MASSIVE family, with lineages that lead to the aztecs, polish, and much much more. It's pretty difficult for me to write all the lines down on a piece of paper.

What would I use to hold those family trees?

Where would I get my information for my family tree?

What about documents and wills?

What if they don't have the same last name as me?

What if some of my family members lived in a different country?

If I have many living relatives, would it be ok to have a family Reunion?

Answer (score 2):

Your questions are so broad that they can't really be answered.  You should start reading how to conduct genealogy research first.

Start here: https://www.archives.gov/research/genealogy

Software: dozens of choices, from opensource (GRAMPS) to web-based (ancestry.com)

Pick an application to start with and just start filling in the information you know.  Different last names are expected; different countries are expected...not an issue.  The link above provides advice about where to go to find more data.  Some sources are free, most are not.

Whether to have a family reunion isn't a genealogy question...if you want one, have one